# why chrome.runtime undefined by http but work fine by https

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When i debug javaScript on devtool.

```
   chrome.runtime
```

see "http://www.qq.com",it show:
**chrome.runtime is undefined.**   see [http preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mlzM.png).

But when i debug it on https site (https://www.qq.com ).it work fine. see [https preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeQuP.png).

tips: all script run on top frame.

Can i change  "chorme:flags"  to enable it ?

Comment: seems that you match only url pattern `http://www.qq.com/*` in your manifest file. Try `*://www.qq.com/*`

Comment: This is the new intended behavior, see https://crbug.com/835287

Answer (score 2):

i got why now.

"chrome.runtime.sendMessage"  not exist when no extension installed.---since chrome 66+.
see:https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=835287

> Comment 29 by rdevlin....@chromium.org, Apr 25 For at least some of
>   these cases from the duped bugs, I think this was caused by revision
>   39f8939309fe39bccc17fa1280b6c7f25c411947.  This modified the
>   externally_connectable property of the cryptotoken component extension
>   (automatically built into Chrome) to only accept incoming connections
>   from https URLs, whereas previously it was all URLs.  When it was set
>   to all URLs, chrome.runtime.sendMessage would always be available
>   because any URL could potentially send a message to the cryptotoken
>   component extension.
>
> However, this is working as intended.  The cryptotoken extension only
>   accepts connections from https origins (so any others would be
>   ignored), and sending a message to any other extension would require
>   the receiving extension to list the URL in the externally_connectable
>   options.  Additionally, this means that before, any extension relying
>   on this behavior would likely have failed to send the message, but
>   done so asynchronously (once the message failed to find an appropriate
>   receiver) rather than synchronously (since runtime is undefined).  If
>   the extension lists the URL in externally_connectable, then
>   chrome.runtime should still be present.  If the extension does not
>   list the site in externally_connectable, then chrome.runtime not being
>   available is intended behavior.
>
> Is there any case in which chrome.runtime is undefined for
>   non-sandboxed chrome-extension:// pages, or for web pages where an
>   installed extension specifies that web page's URL in the
>   externally_connectable field of the manifest?  If so, please attach an
>   extension that demonstrates this issue.  If not, this sounds like it's
>   WAI.

fix: add one extionsion with:manifest.

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "ids": [
      "*"
    ],
    "matches": [
      "http://test.yoursite.in:9090/*",
      "*://*.chromium.org/*"
    ]
  },
```

thinks all.